# c# How use font variant (subscript), with example

Tags: c#

Could you help me to understand the msdn documentation?

I'd need subsripts in a command prompt program like:

```
string abc;
 //change style
Console.WriteLine(abc);
```

I found this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontvariants(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.capitals(v=vs.110).aspx

Could you give an example code how to use it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you only can use one font at once in command prompt.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't print the unicode.

Comment: @Hegedus.Cs Hi, didn't the the answer that I used to mark this answer as duplicate solved your problem? If I understood correctly you want to print out subsrcipts in the console. If that's not correct please let me know, in order to unmark the question as duplicate. If so please make more clear of what you are looking for by providing an input and an expected output. Thanks !